# Swift : Swipe Both UICollectionView and UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I have created this interface with `collectionView` for tabs and `pageViewController` for swiping pages and am getting the index of page when  i swipe but not able to change `collectionViewTab` how to change it? Anyone tell me, how to Update `collectionViewTab` bottom indicator???

```
 func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {

  }
```

in this I am getting correct page index:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path.
When you swipe on `UIPageViewController`, you get current page index. You should be saving that index to class variable and use it in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to determine if tab index matches currently displayed `UIPageViewController`. So something like this should work:

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

      if indexPath.item == classIndexVariable {
        bottomIndicator.isHidden = false // show indicator at current position
      }else{
        bottomIndicator.isHidden = true // hide indicator from all only shows in matched condition
       }

      return cell
    }
```

To explain:
In the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you have to compare current cell index with index you saved in `UIPageViewController didFinishAnimating` function. If it matches you have active tab - show bottom indicator. If index doesn't match, you tab is not active so don't show bottom indicator.

**As I said, please keep in mind this is just a snipper. Don't know what you code looks like, I am guessing you are doing something like this.**

Comment: I did Exactly U said U gave Correct Solution  it worked for me Thanks